# Use lambda function for multiple replacement python

Tags: python, pandas

I have sample dataset `df` like;

```
tel_no
 tel:+1-860-752-8792
 tel:+1-949-722-8838
```

Th goal is to get the output as;

```
tel_no
18607528792
19497228838
```

Here is my attempt;

```
df['tel_no'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(i, '') for i in ['+','-','tel:'])
```

But this gives an error message;

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

I am aware that it can be done in 3 separate lines, on for each character. But I was wondering can we do it one line as above. Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you simply wrote a named function rather than a nameless/undebuggable lambda, you could debug it IYSWIM, even if only by using print statements to observe input/output

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to go would be to use pandas `str` methods, namely `findall` (to find all digits using the regex `\d+`) and `join` (to join the resulting list of digit substrings together):

```
>>> df.tel_no.str.findall("\d+").str.join("")

0    18607528792
1    19497228838
Name: tel_no, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [using regex matching is a good solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69291185/2954547), but I can at least address the problem with your code.

You current code is:

```py
df['tel_no'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(i, '') for i in ['+','-','tel:'])
```

Python parses this (perhaps surprisingly) as:

```py
df['tel_no'].apply(
    (
        (lambda x: x.replace(i, ''))
        for i in ['+','-','tel:'])
    )
)
```

That is, **you have written a generator comprehension, creating a new anonymous function at each iteration of the loop**. You have *not* created a single anonymous function with a generator comprehension inside it!

Obviously, generators are not callable, which is what caused the error.

Your attempt reflects two additional misunderstandings:

1. Comprehension syntax cannot be used outside of an actual comprehension. Perhaps you meant to write `lambda x: (x.replace(i, '')) for i in ['+','-','tel:'])`, which would at least be *one* function that *contains* a generator comprehension.
2. String functions like `str.replace` do not *modify* the string. They return a *new* string. See the example below.

```py
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = s1.replace('e', 'f')

# s1 will be unchanged
assert s1 == 'hello'

# s2 will be changed
assert s2 == 'hfllo'
```

To write this as a function, you would need to use `def`, not `lambda:

```py
def clean_tel(x):
    for bad_string in ['+', '-', 'tel:']:
        x = x.replace(bad_string, '')
    return x

df['tel_no'].apply(clean_tel)
```

Or you can omit the loop and write it like this:

```py
df['tel_no'].apply(
    lambda x: x.replace('+', '').replace('-', '').replace('tel:', '')
)
```